# Exchange CSS colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, skin

I want to be able to give my users the possibility to change the color scheme of my website (skins), however I already have 3 different CSS files that deal with the responsive design. I wanted to be able to add the possibility of changing the color scheme without having to create 3 different CSS files for each color scheme, thus optimizing the amount of CSS files I have to maintain and remember to alter every time I make a change to the main CSS color scheme files.

So my question is, is there a way to say: whenever the color is #BC37ED change it to #3748ed, for instance? Maybe using JavaScript or even in the CSS file itself?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try using LESS or Sass and their variables. You'll still have to change the values of the variables before you create each color scheme, but it should be much easier than having to manually find and replace each color.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class or classes for each scheme and then substitute based on user selection using jquery.

Comment: Sure.  Have you decided how you'll do it?

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I need to go learn how to use both of these techniques so I can choose between them. Meanwhile what I did was I kept the main CSS files and I striped the color ones to just the colors and used media queries to limit the number of files. It worked, still left me with a hard maintenance. And someone also mentioned the possibility of using php. So, I’m off to research these options and see which one fits best. But you’ve at least pointed me on the right direction, which to a beginner is a humongous help! Thank you so much!